# Easy edit and delete row from mysql

Tags: mysql, database, datatable

I'm not that good at mysql but some of my tables has this line where I can edit and delete the row easy without writing any SQL? How can I make that row inside another table?

Comment: Do you have a gui (mysqlworkbench,phpmyadmin,heidisql,toad)?

Comment: I don't know what that is :/

Comment: How are you interfacing with mysql then?

Comment: Oh, I'm using PHPmyAdmin I can see ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use any GUI editor like phpmyadmin or the tools which P.Salmon mentioned.

Using GUI editor, you can connect to the database using connection string and you can view tables and see the result which can edited and deleted.[image]

Comment: I'm using PhpMyAdmin and I have that line in some tables but not in all?

Comment: Need to create a unique index by selecting one column in the table, then only it will be displayed.